# How to click button by id and innertext?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I use puppeteer to get data from page. It have pagination (1,2,3). I need to click on a different button to open new page. But only difference between the buttons is innerText (1,2,3).

Button 1:

```
<a id="lbnGoToPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GoToPage','')">1</a>
```

Button 2:

```
<a id="lbnGoToPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GoToPage','')">2</a>
```

Button 3:

```
<a id="lbnGoToPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GoToPage','')">3</a>
```

How to select button 2 after I have finish get data from page one?

Comment: That is invalid HTML

Comment: But why not use `document.querySelectorAll('[id=GoToPage]')`

Comment: But how I can use to go to only one page? For example page 2

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[id=GoToPage]')[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using an `XPath` expression using [page.$x](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#pagexexpression):

```js
const [link] = await page.$x('//*[@id="lbnGoToPage"][text() = "3"]');
await link.click();
```

In this case, that would click page "3".

Comment: Can I do this? ```var conlist = [];document.querySelectorAll('#lbnGoToPage').forEach(bt=>{bt.addEventListener('click', ()=>{const link = await page.$x(`//*[@id="lbnGoToPage"][text() = "${bt.innerHTML}"]`);await link.click();conlist.push(link);});});```

Comment: @Weilory what are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: It seems this should be `const [link] = await page.$x();` as returned value is an array?

Comment: Good catch @vsemozhebuty